# Javascript multidimensional array create

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to do multidimensional array to store value `{["SQ",111,222],["SQ1",111,222]}` like this, so how I can modify my Javascript code accordingly?

```
//Collect the stock to array
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) 
{

  var stockName = responseData.ranking_stocks[i].abbr_name; 
  var stockAOM_VALUE = responseData.ranking_stocks[i].aom_value; 
  var stockAOM_VOLUMN = responseData.ranking_stocks[i].aom_volume;

  arrayTopGainStock[i] = stockName;
}
```

Comment: `{["SQ",111,222],["SQ1",111,222]}` <--- what's that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `stockName` would be `SQ`, `stockAOM_VALUE` would be `111` and `stockAOM_VOLUMN` would be `222`.

Then replace this:

```
arrayTopGainStock[i] = stockName;
```

with this:

```
arrayTopGainStock[i] = [stockName, stockAOM_VALUE, stockAOM_VOLUMN];
```